# Enumerate All Cycles Passing Through Vertices at Most k times

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, graph-theory

I have to write an algorithm to produce all cycles in an undirected graph passing through vertices at most k times. I have a Python implementation of such an algorithm for the case k=1 using a recursive depth-first search:

```
def loop_dfs(self, current_node, start_node, graph, current_path, all_loops, nodes_to_faces):

    if some_criteria_to_reject_cycle_is_met:
            return

    if current_node == start_node:
        all_loops.append(shift(list(current_path)))
        return

    else:
        for adjacent_node in set(graph[current_node]):
            if Graph.count(adjacent_node, current_path) < self.rep_num:
                current_path.append(adjacent_node)
                graph[current_node].remove(adjacent_node)
                graph[adjacent_node].remove(current_node)
                self.loop_dfs(adjacent_node, start_node, graph, current_path, all_loops, nodes_to_faces)
                graph[current_node].append(adjacent_node)
                graph[adjacent_node].append(current_node)
                current_path.pop()
```

The list is a variable within a class, hence why nothing is returned here. I'm aware that adjust for the case I desire, I simply need to adjust `self.rep_num` to the desired value of k. However, I've been told that this algorithm has a runtime of `O((kn)^(kn))` (validation of this fact would be appreciated); going from `k=1` to `k=2` takes a two second computation to one that doesn't complete over a day and a half.

I'm looking for a way to speed up this computation by any means necessary, but I've found very little information on doing so. Any thoughts?

Comment: O((kn)^(kn)) is a valid bound. Though there's no particular reason to believe that it's tight for your test graph, I suspect regardless that there are way too many cycles meeting your criteria.

Comment: It is definitely not a tight bound for all graphs, but I have already run into cases where it becomes tighter (i.e. almost complete graphs).